# How to use math symbols in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, interface-builder, symbolic-math

I was wondering if there was a way to get mathematical symbols such as the square root symbol, or plus/minus sign, etc. in interface builder.

These symbols would be on a button or printed out on a label.

(This app is being created for iOS in Xcode 4)

Cheers :)

Comment: Try the `insert Symbol` dialog.

Answer (score 4):

In the U.S. keyboard layout, the square root symbol (√) is Option-v.  The plus/minus symbol (±) is Option-Shift-=.  In general, you just type the symbol you're interested in.  See the Keyboard Viewer to learn how to type a given symbol.  To enable the Keyboard Viewer go to System Preferences > Keyboard pane > Keyboard tab > Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar.

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me !    option - V is √

Answer (score 0):

In latest XCode 7, click Edit-> Emoji & Symbols -> Small Command Icon at the top right -> select Math Symbols on the left pane